# C# String splitting - breaking string up at second comma

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string like so:

```
mystring = "test1, 1, anotherstring, 5, yetanother, 400";
```

myarray can be of varying length. What I would like to do is split the string up like so:

```
{"test1, 1"} 
{"anotherstring, 5}
{"yetanother, 400"}
```

Is this possible? I tried `string[] newArray = mystring.Split(',')` but that splits it at every comma, and not the second comma which is what I'd like to do.

Thanks for your help

Zaps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match two items in the string:

```
string[] parts =
  Regex.Matches(myarray[0], "([^,]*,[^,]*)(?:, |$)")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
  .ToArray();
```

This gets the items from the first string in the array. I don't know why you have the string in an array and if you have more than one string, in that case you have to loop through them and get the items from each string.

Comment: I like this. I think it's most readable (i.e. no maths) and least prone to off by one bugs etc. +1

Comment: A somewhat simpler regular expression is @"\w+,\s+\w+"

Comment: @Jim: Yes, it works for the specific string in the example, but fails for example with `"test, 1, lost+found, 2"` or `"test, 1, , 2"`.

Comment: Possibly, although it means that values with non-word chars, spaces, empty values and the like will not make it through. Guffa's regex allows everything except commas, which is better IMO.

Comment: Actually @guffa, you are selecting the entire match which includes a trailing comma. Better to .Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value) instead.

Comment: @spender: Yes, you are right. That's what I usually do, I missed it this time.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way to make String.Split do this.

If performance is not a concern, you can use LINQ:

```
var input = "test1, 1, anotherstring, 5, yetanother, 400";

string[] result = input.Split(',');
result = result.Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 0)
               .Zip(result.Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 1), (a, b) => a + ", " + b)
               .ToArray();
```

Otherwise you'll probably have to split the string manually using String.IndexOf, or using a regular expression.

Comment: +1 because `Zip` is excellent. this will only work in 4.0+ tho.

Answer (score 2):

Another LINQ-based solution here. (Perhaps not the most efficient, but it allows for concise code and works for grouping into arbitrary group sizes).

---

**1)** Define a new query operator, `InGroupsOf`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> InGroupsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> parts,
                                             int groupSize)
{
    IEnumerable<T> partsLeft = parts;
    while (partsLeft.Count() >= groupSize)
    {
        yield return partsLeft.Take(groupSize).ToArray<T>();
        partsLeft = partsLeft.Skip(groupSize);
    }
}
```

---

**2)** Second, apply it to your input:

```
// define your input string:
string input = "test1, 1, anotherstring, 5, yetanother, 400";

// split it, remove excessive whitespace from all parts, and group them together:
IEnumerable<string[]> pairedInput = input
                                    .Split(',')
                                    .Select(part => part.Trim())
                                    .InGroupsOf(2);  // <-- used here!

// see if it worked:
foreach (string[] pair in pairedInput)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", pair));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with `Split` alone, but it can certainly be achieved.

I take it that `myarray` is actually a string, and not an array...?

In that case, you could perhaps do something like this:

```
string myarray = "test1, 1, anotherstring, 5, yetanother, 400";

string[] sourceArray = myarray.Split(',');
string[] newArray = sourceArray.Select((s,i) =>
   (i % 2 == 0) ? "" : string.Concat(sourceArray[i-1], ",", s).Trim()
).Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: apologies - yes myarray is a string. I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a Regular Expression on the original string to replace every other comma with a different 'token', e.g. ';' 
Then just call string.split on the new token instead.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question... I'd do it like this:

```
string input = "test1, 1, anotherstring, 5, yetanother, 400";
string pattern = @"([^,]*,[^,]*),";

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern).Where(s => s!="").Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
```

You get exactly what you want. Only its dirty... =P  =)

Answer (score 0):

using IEnumerator..

```
       var myarray = "test1, 1, anotherstring, 5, yetanother, 400";
       System.Collections.IEnumerator iEN = myarray.Split(',').GetEnumerator();
       var strList = new List<string>();
       while (iEN.MoveNext())
       {
           var first = iEN.Current;
           iEN.MoveNext();
           strList.Add((string)first + "," + (string)iEN.Current);
       }
```

:)