# Javascript String splitting - breaking string up at second comma

Tags: javascript, string, split

According to this: [C# String splitting - breaking string up at second comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254680/c-sharp-string-splitting-breaking-string-up-at-second-comma)

How can I do the same in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mystring = "test1, 1, anotherstring, 5, yetanother, 400";

var subString = mystring.slice(0,mystring.indexOf(',',mystring.indexOf(',')+1));
```

Or more pretty:

```
var index = mystring.indexOf(',',mystring.indexOf(',')+1);
var substring = mystring.slice(0,index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this...

```
var str="test1, 1, anotherstring, 5, yetanother, 400"; 
var n=str.match("([^,]*,[^,]*)(?:, |$)");
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it without regular expressions:

```
var splitAtSecondComma = function (str) {
    var arr2 = str.split(",");
    var arr1 = arr2.splice(0,2);
    return [arr1.join(","), arr2.join(",")];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
function splitSecondComma(str) {
  var arr = str.split(","),
  l = arr.length,
  arr2 = [];
  for(i= 0; i < l; i= i+2) {
    arr2.push(arr[i] + " " + arr[i+1]);
  }
  return arr2
}
```